# How to set a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship in the same polymorphic model

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I have 3 models, `User`,  `Member`, `Team`.

A `User` can have many `Members` belonging to it. It can then assign those members to `Teams` that belong to `User`.

A `Team` can also have multiple `Members` belonging to it. I am using a polymorphic relationship with `Member` so that both `User` can create a member that is linked to it, and `Team` can create a member which is linked to it.

I want to be able to see which `User` a `Member` entry belongs to (since it can only belong to one user) and also all of the `Teams` that the `Member` is linked to. Therefore, `Member` has a one-to-one relationship with `User`, and a one-to-many relationship with `Team`.

I can link the `Member` to the `User` because I have set a `linked_to_user` field representing the `User`'s id, and a `user_id` field is the id of the user that is a member of `User`.

My question: Is there a way that I can see what `Teams` a `Member` belongs to without having to state the `team_id` in the member record? Same thing for the one `User` it is linked to. A polymorphic way

Below is all my code for reference:

Migrations

```
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('linked_user_id');  //the user that member is linked to
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');    //the user that is a member of linked_user_id
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("memberable_id");
    $table->string("memberable_type");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();  //id of user the team belongs to
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Models

```
class Member extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function memberable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function linkedUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "linked_user_id");
    }

}
```

```
class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Member::class, "memberable");
    }

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Member::class, "memberable");
    }

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: can a member be part of multiple teams at once ? Why is there a morph relation between team and member in your Team model ?

Comment: Yes. A Member can for example belong to Team 1 and Team 2.  Because I want to be able to create a Member from both User and Team models, so a Member can belong to either a User or Team model. So then I can easily access the Members that belong to the Team model and the members that belong to the User model seperately

Comment: the member being able to belong to one or more teams has nothing to do with access or fonctionlity. it's just to know if the relation in one to many or many to many. either ways you can do everything with both options.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How can I do it the polymorphic way for both User and Teams?